# How to reconnect a Console?

Tags: datagrip

I am fairly new to DataGrip, and couldn't figure out how to reconnect an existing console. My Redshift connection disconnects if the connection is inactive for more than 20 minutes, and to reconnect I have to restart the console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now I have just tried to wait for 20 minutes and then run statements and all was ok.
Anyway, try to choose "Disconnect" from context menu of your data source and then run statements in console again (so, the console will restore "broken" connection and it might work).